# Running flyway commands from command line using spring boot properties for maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, flyway

I have a spring boot project using maven that I've included flyway in:

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and application.properties:

```
#LOCAL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/theDatabase
spring.datasource.username=theRightUser
spring.datasource.password=theRightPassword
```

and it works as expected when I run the application.

However, I'm trying to run `mvn flyway:clean` from the command line, and it doesn't seem to recognize the configuration correctly:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.4.4:clean (default-cli) on project my-service: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]
```

I tried adding `spring.flyway` properties (user/pass/url) in the application.properties file but it gave me the same error. What do I need to do to get flyway to read from the application.properies like it does when the application runs normally?

---

EDIT: I have made slight progress: I was able to reference my `application.properties` as a flyway config file by adding this to the pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFiles>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</configFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So now in that file, I have `flyway.url`, `flyway.user` and `flyway.password`. This allows me to run flyway goals from the command line, but is not totally the solution I want. I am looking into using this plugin to try and read the properties into the pom.xml file, and then using those values in the `flyway-maven-plugin`'s `<configuration>` area.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

which would allow me to do this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
                <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
                <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run flyway as maven goal it will not pick up the properties from the `application.properties`, instead it will use the `configuration` provided by the `flyway-maven-plugin`, you can configure the flyway-maven-plugin in the following way -

Add the following plugin to `pom.xml` -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Then we will configure the `flyway-maven-plugin`, the Flyway Maven plugin can be configured in a wide variety of following ways (most convenient),

**Configuration section of the plugin**

The easiest way is to simply use the plugin’s configuration section in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${project.build.directory}/db/flyway_sample;shutdown=true</url>
        <user>SA</user>
        <password>mySecretPwd</password>
        <connectRetries>10</connectRetries>
        <initSql>SET ROLE 'myuser'</initSql>
        <schemas>
            <schema>schema1</schema>
            <schema>schema2</schema>
            <schema>schema3</schema>
        </schemas>
        <callbacks>
            <callback>com.mycompany.project.CustomCallback</callback>
            <callback>com.mycompany.project.AnotherCallback</callback>
        </callbacks>
        <skipDefaultCallbacks>false</skipDefaultCallbacks>
        <cleanDisabled>false</cleanDisabled>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <configFiles>
            <configFile>myConfig.conf</configFile>
            <configFile>other.conf</configFile>
        </configFiles>
        <workingDirectory>/my/working/dir</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Maven properties**

To make it easy to work with Maven profiles and to logically group configuration, the Flyway Maven plugin also supports Maven properties, update the properties section in `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <!-- Properties are prefixed with flyway. -->
        <flyway.user>myUser</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>mySecretPwd</flyway.password>

        <!-- List are defined as comma-separated values -->
        <flyway.schemas>schema1,schema2,schema3</flyway.schemas>

        <!-- Individual placeholders are prefixed by flyway.placeholders. -->
        <flyway.placeholders.keyABC>valueXYZ</flyway.placeholders.keyABC>
        <flyway.placeholders.otherplaceholder>value123</flyway.placeholders.otherplaceholder>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

**External Configuration File**

Another way is to create a separate `.properties` file, the default configuration file name is flyway.properties and it should reside in the same directory as the pom.xml file. Encoding is specified by flyway.encoding (Default is UTF-8):

```
flyway.user=databaseUser
flyway.password=databasePassword
flyway.schemas=schemaName
...
```

If you are using any other name (e.g customConfig.properties) as the configuration file, then it should be specified explicitly when invoking the Maven command:

```
$ mvn <goals> -Dflyway.configFile=customConfig.properties
```

After configuring your `flyway-maven-plugin`, with the desired configuration, we will be able to execute flyway maven goals from command line.

You can do further reading [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! I appreciate the effort, but I am trying to have the pom read the properties dynamically, and then use those values to configure flyway. I've edited my question, I am trying to use the `properties-maven-plugin` to try and accomplish this goal.